# Trying to get random element from arrays

Tags: java, random

What I am trying to do is make a card class that will randomly generate a card by randomly generating a value, and a suit.  I dont care if it creates 4 of the exact same cards, that is not a concern to me.  But below is what I would consider my best attempt so far.

```
String[] PossCards = new String[]{"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
String[] PossSuits = new String[]{"C", "S", "H", "D"};
Random rand = new Random();

public Card(){

    String Card = PossCards[rand.nextInt(PossCards.length)];
    String Suit = PossSuits[rand.nextInt(PossSuits.length)]; 

    String ActCard = Suit + "" + Card;
}
```

This does not work though, When I use my Hand class to try and create 4 random cards, the values that come back are "null null null null". Is the mistake in the above code? Or is it something that i must be mistaking in my hand class?

Comment: Keep in mind java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lowercase characters.

Comment: Please post a SSCCE to reproduce your error.

Comment: Do you store the ActCard value somehow? How do you print the result, that gets to be nulls? Post the whole code...

Comment: I agree with @ppeterka66.  I'd like to see how this is being printed out.  I'd also like to see the class declaration.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

First the naming convention for java - use lowercase characters for variables and methods.

Then you switched the .length method for Cards and Suits, so you should have this :

```
String Suit = PossCards[rand.nextInt(PossCards.length)];
String Card = PossSuits[rand.nextInt(PossSuits.length)];
```

The working example looks like this (dont know, why your example doesnt work - probably the error was in a code you didnt share with us) :

```
public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static String[] possCards = new String[]{"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    public static String[] possSuits = new String[]{"C", "S", "H", "D"};
    public static Random rand = new Random();

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (1<2){
            System.out.println(card());
        }
    }

    public static String card() {
        String suit = possSuits[rand.nextInt(possSuits.length)];
        String card = possCards[rand.nextInt(possCards.length)];

        return suit + card;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's problem. Note that the naming convention is an advice and it is not part of the answer.

Comment: Suit from card array still but does not explain why nulls

Comment: If the variable switcheroo was the problem, IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions would be thrown, not null values.

Comment: Lol I was the only one who answers and I copy the whole tested working example and what you give me? From -2 to -3, cause I switched suit with cards (which is good to point out, but it really does not change ANYTHING in this example, only the order of two letters representing cards).

Comment: The sad thing here is that OP can't explain the problem. And yes, anyone could just make a working example from that piece of code (that's not something great though), but what other people was asking to OP is to show **how** this wasn't working in **his/her** environment. But thanks to you, OP just need to copy/paste this code without even thinking why it worked when compared with him/hers.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the length of PossCards as limit of PossSuits ramdom number

you are doing:

```
String Suit = PossCards[rand.nextInt(PossSuits.length)];
String Card = PossSuits[rand.nextInt(PossCards.length)];
```

and you should do:

```
String Card = PossCards[rand.nextInt(PossCards.length)];
String Suit = PossSuits[rand.nextInt(PossSuits.length)];
```